# as.numeric("10^3") Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion

Tags: r, character, numeric, coerce

Trying to coerce this vector as numeric:

```
vec <- c("10^2", "10^3", "10^6", "", "10^9")

vec <- as.numeric(vec)

[1] NA NA NA NA NA

Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Output desired:

[1] "100"   "1000"  "1e+06" ""      "1e+09"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split the strings at `^` and then coerce each part individually. We have to escape using `\\` because `^` is a special regex character.

```
sapply(strsplit(vec, "\\^"), function(x){
    as.numeric(x[1])^as.numeric(x[2])
})
#[1] 1e+02 1e+03 1e+06    NA 1e+09
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, we can use `eval(parse` as it is a expression

```
lst1 <- lapply(vec, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
lst[sapply(lst1, is.null)] <- NA
unlist(lst1)
#[1] 1e+02 1e+03 1e+06    NA 1e+09
```

---

Or in a compact way, `replace` the blank (`""`) with `NA` and then do the `eval(parse`

```
sapply(replace(vec, vec == "", NA), function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
```

---

Or another option is to `read` with `read.table` using `sep` as `^` and then use

```
with(read.table(text = paste(vec, collapse="\n"), sep="^", header = FALSE), V1^V2)
```

Or as @d.b suggested

```
read.table(text = paste(gsub("0\\^", "e", replace(vec, vec == "", NA)),
     collapse="\n"), header = FALSE)
```

Comment: You might as well do `eval(parse(text = paste0("c(", paste(replace(vec, vec == "", NA), collapse = ","), ")")))`

Comment: Also, `read.csv(text = paste(gsub("0\\^", "e", vec), collapse = ","), header = FALSE)`